# Add Empty Subplot With No Axis Ticks/Labels for Text as Subplot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My goal is to create plot with four subplots, where the bottom two are really just empty boxes where I will display some text. Unfortunately, all of my efforts to remove the y and x axis tick marks and labels have failed. I'm still new to matplotlib so I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing. Here's what I'm trying and what I get:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=False, sharey=True, figsize=(6,6))
fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.title('Neuron Length')
plt.xlabel('Strain')
plt.ylabel('Neuron Length (um)')

aIP = fig.add_subplot(223, frameon=False)
aIP.annotate('Big Axes \nGridSpec[1:, -1]', (0.1, 0.5),
               xycoords='axes fraction', va='center')
# First approach
aIP.axes.xaxis.set_ticks([])
aIP.axes.yaxis.set_ticks([])
# Second approach
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: 4x4 grid of empty subplots with x and y labels and tick marks present]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achieved by using `plt.subplots()` to draw four of them and remove the bottom left frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1000)
x1 = np.sin(2*t)
x2 = np.cos(2*t)
x3 = x1 + x2

fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(6,6), sharex=True, sharey=True)

axes[0,0].plot(t, x1, linewidth=2)
axes[0,1].plot(t, x2, linewidth=2)
axes[1,1].plot(t, x3, linewidth=2)
axes[1,0].axis('off')　# off
axes[1,0].annotate('Big Axes \nGridSpec[1:, -1]', (0.1, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', va='center')

fig.suptitle('Neuron Length')

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Strain', ylabel='Neuron Length (um)')

plt.show()
```

[image]